# What an effect the location of quantifier has in such predicate logics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let's say we have a logical expression such that;

> $\forall $y( $\theta$(x,y) $\implies$ $\forall$x$\beta$(x) ) )

Can we safely say that it is "logically equivalent" to

> $\forall$y$\forall$x( $\theta$(x,y) $\implies$ $\beta$(x) )

Comment: The problem with the first expression is that the first occurrence of $x$ is not bound by any quantifier. That is the scope of the universally quantified variable $x$ applies only to $\beta(x).$

Comment: In the second expression, all variables are within the scope of their quantifiers.

Comment: So could not we say, first x is a free variable and than the case is true for every x value? @amWhy

Comment: No, that isn't the case. Yes, x is a free variable. But as such, it may as well be called $z$: That makes the problem more explicit: $\forall y(\theta(z, y) \rightarrow \forall x\beta (x))$. That makes little sense, and shows no relation between x, y. If we want each $"x"$ in $\theta(x, y)$ to be the same "$x$" as referred to in $\beta(x)$, then you need the quantifier for $x$ to be in the front, as in the second expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $\theta(x, y)$ means $y$ is an aardvark and $x$ is the daughter of $y$ and that $\beta(x)$ means that $x$ is an aardvark.
Then:

$$\forall y(\theta(x, y) \implies \forall x \beta(x)) \tag{*}$$

is equivalent to:

$$\forall y(\theta(x, y) \implies \forall z \beta(z))$$

(because the names of bound variables don't matter) and is the (rather remarkable) statement about an individual $x$ that 
says that if $x$ is the daughter of an aardvark then every individual
is an aardvark.

On the other hand:

$$\forall y\forall x(\theta(x, y) \implies \beta(x)) \tag{**}$$

is the unexceptionable statement that the daughter of any aardvark is an aardvark.

So (*) and (**) are certainly not  logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The first statement has a free variable, but the second has not, so we can't say they are equivalent as pointed out by some of the comments.

But we can extend the notion of equivalence to expressions with free variables, e.g. $\neg \neg P(x)$ is equivalent to $P(x)$, since the exact same objects that satisfy the first statement satisfy the second statement. I am thinking that that is maybe what you were really asking.

Also, you may have been wondering about the move of the quantifier. Again, when we make sure we don't have any differences in free variables, you get the equivalence you are suspecting, e.g. $\forall y \: (P(y) \rightarrow \forall x \: R(x,y))$ is indeed equivalent to $\forall y \forall x \: (P(y) \rightarrow R(x,y))$.

You have to be careful in moving quantifiers though, e.g. $\forall y \: ( \forall x \: R(x,y) \rightarrow P(y))$ is not equivalent to $\forall y \forall x \: ( R(x,y) \rightarrow P(y))$, but to $\forall y \exists x \: ( R(x,y) \rightarrow P(y))$.

Comment: First sentence: correct.  But.....I think, using your example, the OP was asking whether $\forall y(R(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x P(x))$, was logically equivalent to the proper claim $\forall y \forall x (R(x, y) \rightarrow P(x))$. (It is not). In other words you're answering a question that wasn't asked.

Comment: You showed, in other words, a situation where one expression is equivalent to the other, but the OP is concerned about how to quantify variables when the first predicate (the antecedant) involves two arguments, and the predicate (the consequent) is a unary Predicate.